# GCC - Linking is unsuccessful

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, rtems

and sorry for my not really good english. I'll try my best :)

I am trying to compile a addin for my Casio graphic calculator in C. This works without problems when using the official SDK. Because it is only available for Windows, I want to use gcc.

So I got *sh-rtems-gcc* and it's binutils from macports and tried to compile my program according to [this instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fxsdk/wiki/UsingGCC). I copy-pasted the described *addin.ld* and *crt0.s* and placed my *main.c* and *libfxsys.a* (from the same guys as the instructions mentioned above) in the same directory. The sub-dir *include* contains fxsys' headers. I verified the presence of all the functions of the library in the .a file with nm.

When using this command for compilation:

```
sh-rtems-gcc-4.2.3 -m3 -mb -nostdlib -I./include -c crt0.s main.c
```

Everything works fine. But then im trying to link:

```
sh-rtems-gcc-4.2.3 -m3 -mb -nostdlib -L. -o myaddin.elf -Taddin.ld crt0.o main.o -lfxsys
```

and get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `__main':
main.c:(.text+0x248): undefined reference to `_Bdisp_AllClr_VRAM'
...     
... (--- cut 16 other errors in the same format ---)
...
main.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `_Sleep'
./libfxsys.a(locate.o): In function `_locate':
locate.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `_locate_OS'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

All the missing symbols are in the *libfxsys.a*. I have verified this with nm.

I have already played with the positions of the library in the command, as this is often mentioned as a source of failure in other posts found in google, but without success. I also tried adding and removing the -*lgcc* option that is used in the above mentioned instructions, without success.

My Host-Machine is a Intel Mac, OS X 10.6

Because I have no idea how to solve this problem, and get to compile my program, I have to ask: What am I doing wrong? How can I compile my program without using the SDK?

Thanks in advance,
xythobuz

**Edit:**

I have also tried linking with:

```
sh-rtems-ld -EB -L. -o myaddin.elf -Taddin.ld crt0.o --start-group main.o libfxsys.a --end-group
```

But it produces the same output as above.

Comment: Perhaps `sh-rtems-gcc-4.2.3` has `-v`(verbose) option that could give you a hint

Comment: I have tried it, but it gives no related information... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say the exact problem, but would investigate like this:

1. Find the library that contains the missing symbols. Use `nm` to see symbol names
2. Once you know which library contains the symbols  make sure you're linking to it, and in the correct order.  Try using recursive symbol resolution options  `-(` `-)` with your linker.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't expressed myself clearly...

I already know for sure that all the missing symbols are in the *libfxsys.a*. I'm linking to it with *-lfxsys*.
But I don't know what you mean with *recursive symbol resolution options* and a quick google search hasn't turned up anything. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: By default the binutils linker ld will only pull in a symbol from a library if code it has already seen has requested it. So "ld foo.lib and needsfoolib.o" will not work, you need "ld needsfoolib.o foo.lib" or to use recursive symbol resolution options like "ld --start-group foo.lib needsfoolib.o --end-group". For more info "man ld" and look at the --start-group --end-group -- AKA -( and -) -- options .

Comment: I have tried it (see question for command), but it produces the same errors as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: `nm` on main.o and libfxsys.a.  Are the exact symbol names really present, with proper "T" or "t" types (text seg) not "U" or "u" (undefined) ?

Comment: Okay, i got it. Main tried to call (e.g.) *_locate()*, but this lib defined *locate()*. Changing some lines in the lib source cured my problem. Thank you very much!!